# Kafka Schema Registry - Schema Referring a Union Schema Giving Server Error

Tags: java, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have many different Enums to be used which is common for many different Schemas, In order to reuse them across we have defined common Schema called commonTypes.avsc like below

```
[
    {
        "namespace": "org.example.test",
        "type": "enum",
        "name":"EventType",
        "symbols":
            ["CREATE","UPDATE","DELETE"]
    },
    {
        "namespace": "org.example.test",
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "EventState",
        "symbols":  ["OPEN","PROCESSED","CLOSED"]       
    },
    {
        "namespace": "org.example.test",
        "type": "enum",
        "name":"SEVERITY",
        "symbols":
            ["CRITICAL","HIGH","LOW"]
    }
]
```

And i'm referring them in many different schemas and one of them is like below (Miminalistic example)

```
{
    "namespace": "org.example.test",
    "type": "record",    
    "name": "Event",
    "imports": ["CommonTypes.avsc"],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "eventType",
            "type": "org.example.test.EventType"
        },
        {
            "name": "Id",
            "type": [
                        "null",
                        "long"
                ],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "eventState",
            "type": "org.example.test.EventState"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i've first registered the CommonTypes.avsc with subject name "commontypes-value" in the schema registry which is successfull.
And when i register the event schema with below value for "references"

```
"references": [
    {
       "name": "org.example.test.EventType",
       "subject":  "commontypes-value",
       "version": "1"
    },
    {
       "name": "org.example.test.EventState",
       "subject":  "commontypes-value",
       "version": "1"
    }
  ]
```

The request fails with internal Server.  And when i check Schema Registry server log - I can see below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.Schema$NamedSchema (org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema and org.apache.avro.Schema$NamedSchema are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Names.add(Schema.java:1505)
    at org.apache.avro.Schemas.toString(Schemas.java:43)
    at org.apache.avro.Schemas.toString(Schemas.java:30)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchema.canonicalString(AvroSchema.java:152)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.canonicalizeSchema(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:926)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.lookUpSchemaUnderSubject(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:744)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:565)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:266)
```

Comment: I dont think you can define more than one enum in a file like that. What happens if you separate them, then update `imports` array in the other file to include type + state enum files?

Comment: @OneCricketeer definitely that is one way. That will work fine in case of schema registration.  But the thing is we were not using schema registry till now and directly using the schema in producer and consumers, And above approach was working fine.
Since now we are going for schema registry, this approach doesn;t work.
So i wanted to be sure if there is any other way, than putting each enum in seperate file, before going for it.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could use an AVDL file with all enums declared, then the Avro maven plugin can generate AVSC for you, or use the rendered Java model in producer definitions, and the registration would automatically happen based on that serialized object... That's what I always did, but I used the registry before references were introduced, so I don't know if that's best practice